# Bloom Filtering with CRC64 hashing functions doesn't yield theoritical false positive figure

Tags: algorithm, hash, probability, bloom-filter

It is possible to calculate the expected false positive probability (p) of a Bloom Filter with the number of items (n) in the filter, the number of entries (m) in the filter, and the number of hash functions (k) using the following formula:

p(false) = (1 - (1 − 1/m)ᵏⁿ)ᵏ

Additionally, one can compute the false positive probability through simulation. This is valuable for validating that the hash functions exhibit properties of good randomness to minimize collisions. The process involves inserting n items into a Bloom filter using random numbers generated from a uniform integer random distribution in the first step. In the second step, a substantial number of random items not present in the inserted Bloom filter set are generated. These items are then hashed using k hash functions and tested against the n-member set in the Bloom filter. Since all of them are true negatives, calculating the false positive rate becomes straightforward using the count of positive tests returned.

When employing the well-known SipHash hashing function, the computed false positives align with the simulation. However, discrepancies arise when using CRC64 as a hashing function with different seeds as a prefix message. The computed false positives do not match the simulation results. I am seeking an explanation for why CRC64 hashing fails to provide the expected false probability. It is important to note that I acknowledge the possibility of an error in my code. Below, I have included both the results and the code for review.

Can someone provide a detailed explanation as to why CRC64 hashing deviates from the expected false probability? I require an answer that delves deeper than simply stating that CRC64 is not a suitable hashing function.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <bitset>
#include <cassert>

/* <MIT License>
 Copyright (c) 2013  Marek Majkowski <marek@popcount.org>
 (...)
 </MIT License>
 Original location:
    https://github.com/majek/csiphash/
 Solution inspired by code from:
    Samuel Neves (supercop/crypto_auth/siphash24/little)
    djb (supercop/crypto_auth/siphash24/little2)
    Jean-Philippe Aumasson (https://131002.net/siphash/siphash24.c)
*/

#if defined(__BYTE_ORDER__) && defined(__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__) && \
   __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#  define _le64toh(x) ((uint64_t)(x))
#elif defined(_WIN32)
/* Windows is always little endian, unless you're on xbox360
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.80).aspx */
#  define _le64toh(x) ((uint64_t)(x))
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#  include <libkern/OSByteOrder.h>
#  define _le64toh(x) OSSwapLittleToHostInt64(x)
#else

/* See: http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Endianness/ */
#  if defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__NetBSD__) || defined(__OpenBSD__)
#    include <sys/endian.h>
#  else
#    include <endian.h>
#  endif
#  if defined(__BYTE_ORDER) && defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN) && \
   __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#    define _le64toh(x) ((uint64_t)(x))
#  else
#    define _le64toh(x) le64toh(x)
#  endif

#endif


#define ROTATE(x, b) (uint64_t)( ((x) << (b)) | ( (x) >> (64 - (b))) )

#define HALF_ROUND(a,b,c,d,s,t) \
   a += b; c += d;                 \
   b = ROTATE(b, s) ^ a;            \
   d = ROTATE(d, t) ^ c;            \
   a = ROTATE(a, 32);

#define DOUBLE_ROUND(v0,v1,v2,v3)       \
   HALF_ROUND(v0,v1,v2,v3,13,16);       \
   HALF_ROUND(v2,v1,v0,v3,17,21);       \
   HALF_ROUND(v0,v1,v2,v3,13,16);       \
   HALF_ROUND(v2,v1,v0,v3,17,21);


uint64_t siphash(const void* src, unsigned long src_sz, const unsigned char* seed) {

   const uint64_t* in = (uint64_t*)src;
   const uint64_t* _key = (uint64_t*)seed;
   uint64_t k0 = _le64toh(_key[0]);
   uint64_t k1 = _le64toh(_key[1]);
   uint64_t b = (uint64_t)src_sz << 56;

   uint64_t v0 = k0 ^ 0x736f6d6570736575ULL;
   uint64_t v1 = k1 ^ 0x646f72616e646f6dULL;
   uint64_t v2 = k0 ^ 0x6c7967656e657261ULL;
   uint64_t v3 = k1 ^ 0x7465646279746573ULL;

   while (src_sz >= 8) {
      uint64_t mi = _le64toh(*in);
      in += 1; src_sz -= 8;
      v3 ^= mi;
      DOUBLE_ROUND(v0, v1, v2, v3);
      v0 ^= mi;
   }

   uint64_t t = 0;
   uint8_t* pt = (uint8_t*)&t;
   uint8_t* m = (uint8_t*)in;

   switch (src_sz) {

   case 7: pt[6] = m[6];
   case 6: pt[5] = m[5];
   case 5: pt[4] = m[4];
   case 4: *((uint32_t*)&pt[0]) = *((uint32_t*)&m[0]);
      break;

   case 3: pt[2] = m[2];
   case 2: pt[1] = m[1];
   case 1: pt[0] = m[0];
   }

   b |= _le64toh(t);
   v3 ^= b;
   DOUBLE_ROUND(v0, v1, v2, v3);
   v0 ^= b;
   v2 ^= 0xff;
   DOUBLE_ROUND(v0, v1, v2, v3);
   DOUBLE_ROUND(v0, v1, v2, v3);

   return (v0 ^ v1) ^ (v2 ^ v3);
};


#define u64 uint64_t
#define u8 uint8_t
#define unint uint32_t

#define CONST64(n) n##ull

#define INITIAL_CRC64 0xffffffffffffffffULL

static const u64 CRC64_Table[256] = {
   CONST64(0x0000000000000000), CONST64(0x42f0e1eba9ea3693),
   CONST64(0x85e1c3d753d46d26), CONST64(0xc711223cfa3e5bb5),
   CONST64(0x493366450e42ecdf), CONST64(0x0bc387aea7a8da4c),
   CONST64(0xccd2a5925d9681f9), CONST64(0x8e224479f47cb76a),
   CONST64(0x9266cc8a1c85d9be), CONST64(0xd0962d61b56fef2d),
   CONST64(0x17870f5d4f51b498), CONST64(0x5577eeb6e6bb820b),
   CONST64(0xdb55aacf12c73561), CONST64(0x99a54b24bb2d03f2),
   CONST64(0x5eb4691841135847), CONST64(0x1c4488f3e8f96ed4),
   CONST64(0x663d78ff90e185ef), CONST64(0x24cd9914390bb37c),
   CONST64(0xe3dcbb28c335e8c9), CONST64(0xa12c5ac36adfde5a),
   CONST64(0x2f0e1eba9ea36930), CONST64(0x6dfeff5137495fa3),
   CONST64(0xaaefdd6dcd770416), CONST64(0xe81f3c86649d3285),
   CONST64(0xf45bb4758c645c51), CONST64(0xb6ab559e258e6ac2),
   CONST64(0x71ba77a2dfb03177), CONST64(0x334a9649765a07e4),
   CONST64(0xbd68d2308226b08e), CONST64(0xff9833db2bcc861d),
   CONST64(0x388911e7d1f2dda8), CONST64(0x7a79f00c7818eb3b),
   CONST64(0xcc7af1ff21c30bde), CONST64(0x8e8a101488293d4d),
   CONST64(0x499b3228721766f8), CONST64(0x0b6bd3c3dbfd506b),
   CONST64(0x854997ba2f81e701), CONST64(0xc7b97651866bd192),
   CONST64(0x00a8546d7c558a27), CONST64(0x4258b586d5bfbcb4),
   CONST64(0x5e1c3d753d46d260), CONST64(0x1cecdc9e94ace4f3),
   CONST64(0xdbfdfea26e92bf46), CONST64(0x990d1f49c77889d5),
   CONST64(0x172f5b3033043ebf), CONST64(0x55dfbadb9aee082c),
   CONST64(0x92ce98e760d05399), CONST64(0xd03e790cc93a650a),
   CONST64(0xaa478900b1228e31), CONST64(0xe8b768eb18c8b8a2),
   CONST64(0x2fa64ad7e2f6e317), CONST64(0x6d56ab3c4b1cd584),
   CONST64(0xe374ef45bf6062ee), CONST64(0xa1840eae168a547d),
   CONST64(0x66952c92ecb40fc8), CONST64(0x2465cd79455e395b),
   CONST64(0x3821458aada7578f), CONST64(0x7ad1a461044d611c),
   CONST64(0xbdc0865dfe733aa9), CONST64(0xff3067b657990c3a),
   CONST64(0x711223cfa3e5bb50), CONST64(0x33e2c2240a0f8dc3),
   CONST64(0xf4f3e018f031d676), CONST64(0xb60301f359dbe0e5),
   CONST64(0xda050215ea6c212f), CONST64(0x98f5e3fe438617bc),
   CONST64(0x5fe4c1c2b9b84c09), CONST64(0x1d14202910527a9a),
   CONST64(0x93366450e42ecdf0), CONST64(0xd1c685bb4dc4fb63),
   CONST64(0x16d7a787b7faa0d6), CONST64(0x5427466c1e109645),
   CONST64(0x4863ce9ff6e9f891), CONST64(0x0a932f745f03ce02),
   CONST64(0xcd820d48a53d95b7), CONST64(0x8f72eca30cd7a324),
   CONST64(0x0150a8daf8ab144e), CONST64(0x43a04931514122dd),
   CONST64(0x84b16b0dab7f7968), CONST64(0xc6418ae602954ffb),
   CONST64(0xbc387aea7a8da4c0), CONST64(0xfec89b01d3679253),
   CONST64(0x39d9b93d2959c9e6), CONST64(0x7b2958d680b3ff75),
   CONST64(0xf50b1caf74cf481f), CONST64(0xb7fbfd44dd257e8c),
   CONST64(0x70eadf78271b2539), CONST64(0x321a3e938ef113aa),
   CONST64(0x2e5eb66066087d7e), CONST64(0x6cae578bcfe24bed),
   CONST64(0xabbf75b735dc1058), CONST64(0xe94f945c9c3626cb),
   CONST64(0x676dd025684a91a1), CONST64(0x259d31cec1a0a732),
   CONST64(0xe28c13f23b9efc87), CONST64(0xa07cf2199274ca14),
   CONST64(0x167ff3eacbaf2af1), CONST64(0x548f120162451c62),
   CONST64(0x939e303d987b47d7), CONST64(0xd16ed1d631917144),
   CONST64(0x5f4c95afc5edc62e), CONST64(0x1dbc74446c07f0bd),
   CONST64(0xdaad56789639ab08), CONST64(0x985db7933fd39d9b),
   CONST64(0x84193f60d72af34f), CONST64(0xc6e9de8b7ec0c5dc),
   CONST64(0x01f8fcb784fe9e69), CONST64(0x43081d5c2d14a8fa),
   CONST64(0xcd2a5925d9681f90), CONST64(0x8fdab8ce70822903),
   CONST64(0x48cb9af28abc72b6), CONST64(0x0a3b7b1923564425),
   CONST64(0x70428b155b4eaf1e), CONST64(0x32b26afef2a4998d),
   CONST64(0xf5a348c2089ac238), CONST64(0xb753a929a170f4ab),
   CONST64(0x3971ed50550c43c1), CONST64(0x7b810cbbfce67552),
   CONST64(0xbc902e8706d82ee7), CONST64(0xfe60cf6caf321874),
   CONST64(0xe224479f47cb76a0), CONST64(0xa0d4a674ee214033),
   CONST64(0x67c58448141f1b86), CONST64(0x253565a3bdf52d15),
   CONST64(0xab1721da49899a7f), CONST64(0xe9e7c031e063acec),
   CONST64(0x2ef6e20d1a5df759), CONST64(0x6c0603e6b3b7c1ca),
   CONST64(0xf6fae5c07d3274cd), CONST64(0xb40a042bd4d8425e),
   CONST64(0x731b26172ee619eb), CONST64(0x31ebc7fc870c2f78),
   CONST64(0xbfc9838573709812), CONST64(0xfd39626eda9aae81),
   CONST64(0x3a28405220a4f534), CONST64(0x78d8a1b9894ec3a7),
   CONST64(0x649c294a61b7ad73), CONST64(0x266cc8a1c85d9be0),
   CONST64(0xe17dea9d3263c055), CONST64(0xa38d0b769b89f6c6),
   CONST64(0x2daf4f0f6ff541ac), CONST64(0x6f5faee4c61f773f),
   CONST64(0xa84e8cd83c212c8a), CONST64(0xeabe6d3395cb1a19),
   CONST64(0x90c79d3fedd3f122), CONST64(0xd2377cd44439c7b1),
   CONST64(0x15265ee8be079c04), CONST64(0x57d6bf0317edaa97),
   CONST64(0xd9f4fb7ae3911dfd), CONST64(0x9b041a914a7b2b6e),
   CONST64(0x5c1538adb04570db), CONST64(0x1ee5d94619af4648),
   CONST64(0x02a151b5f156289c), CONST64(0x4051b05e58bc1e0f),
   CONST64(0x87409262a28245ba), CONST64(0xc5b073890b687329),
   CONST64(0x4b9237f0ff14c443), CONST64(0x0962d61b56fef2d0),
   CONST64(0xce73f427acc0a965), CONST64(0x8c8315cc052a9ff6),
   CONST64(0x3a80143f5cf17f13), CONST64(0x7870f5d4f51b4980),
   CONST64(0xbf61d7e80f251235), CONST64(0xfd913603a6cf24a6),
   CONST64(0x73b3727a52b393cc), CONST64(0x31439391fb59a55f),
   CONST64(0xf652b1ad0167feea), CONST64(0xb4a25046a88dc879),
   CONST64(0xa8e6d8b54074a6ad), CONST64(0xea16395ee99e903e),
   CONST64(0x2d071b6213a0cb8b), CONST64(0x6ff7fa89ba4afd18),
   CONST64(0xe1d5bef04e364a72), CONST64(0xa3255f1be7dc7ce1),
   CONST64(0x64347d271de22754), CONST64(0x26c49cccb40811c7),
   CONST64(0x5cbd6cc0cc10fafc), CONST64(0x1e4d8d2b65facc6f),
   CONST64(0xd95caf179fc497da), CONST64(0x9bac4efc362ea149),
   CONST64(0x158e0a85c2521623), CONST64(0x577eeb6e6bb820b0),
   CONST64(0x906fc95291867b05), CONST64(0xd29f28b9386c4d96),
   CONST64(0xcedba04ad0952342), CONST64(0x8c2b41a1797f15d1),
   CONST64(0x4b3a639d83414e64), CONST64(0x09ca82762aab78f7),
   CONST64(0x87e8c60fded7cf9d), CONST64(0xc51827e4773df90e),
   CONST64(0x020905d88d03a2bb), CONST64(0x40f9e43324e99428),
   CONST64(0x2cffe7d5975e55e2), CONST64(0x6e0f063e3eb46371),
   CONST64(0xa91e2402c48a38c4), CONST64(0xebeec5e96d600e57),
   CONST64(0x65cc8190991cb93d), CONST64(0x273c607b30f68fae),
   CONST64(0xe02d4247cac8d41b), CONST64(0xa2dda3ac6322e288),
   CONST64(0xbe992b5f8bdb8c5c), CONST64(0xfc69cab42231bacf),
   CONST64(0x3b78e888d80fe17a), CONST64(0x7988096371e5d7e9),
   CONST64(0xf7aa4d1a85996083), CONST64(0xb55aacf12c735610),
   CONST64(0x724b8ecdd64d0da5), CONST64(0x30bb6f267fa73b36),
   CONST64(0x4ac29f2a07bfd00d), CONST64(0x08327ec1ae55e69e),
   CONST64(0xcf235cfd546bbd2b), CONST64(0x8dd3bd16fd818bb8),
   CONST64(0x03f1f96f09fd3cd2), CONST64(0x41011884a0170a41),
   CONST64(0x86103ab85a2951f4), CONST64(0xc4e0db53f3c36767),
   CONST64(0xd8a453a01b3a09b3), CONST64(0x9a54b24bb2d03f20),
   CONST64(0x5d45907748ee6495), CONST64(0x1fb5719ce1045206),
   CONST64(0x919735e51578e56c), CONST64(0xd367d40ebc92d3ff),
   CONST64(0x1476f63246ac884a), CONST64(0x568617d9ef46bed9),
   CONST64(0xe085162ab69d5e3c), CONST64(0xa275f7c11f7768af),
   CONST64(0x6564d5fde549331a), CONST64(0x279434164ca30589),
   CONST64(0xa9b6706fb8dfb2e3), CONST64(0xeb46918411358470),
   CONST64(0x2c57b3b8eb0bdfc5), CONST64(0x6ea7525342e1e956),
   CONST64(0x72e3daa0aa188782), CONST64(0x30133b4b03f2b111),
   CONST64(0xf7021977f9cceaa4), CONST64(0xb5f2f89c5026dc37),
   CONST64(0x3bd0bce5a45a6b5d), CONST64(0x79205d0e0db05dce),
   CONST64(0xbe317f32f78e067b), CONST64(0xfcc19ed95e6430e8),
   CONST64(0x86b86ed5267cdbd3), CONST64(0xc4488f3e8f96ed40),
   CONST64(0x0359ad0275a8b6f5), CONST64(0x41a94ce9dc428066),
   CONST64(0xcf8b0890283e370c), CONST64(0x8d7be97b81d4019f),
   CONST64(0x4a6acb477bea5a2a), CONST64(0x089a2aacd2006cb9),
   CONST64(0x14dea25f3af9026d), CONST64(0x562e43b4931334fe),
   CONST64(0x913f6188692d6f4b), CONST64(0xd3cf8063c0c759d8),
   CONST64(0x5dedc41a34bbeeb2), CONST64(0x1f1d25f19d51d821),
   CONST64(0xd80c07cd676f8394), CONST64(0x9afce626ce85b507)
};

uint64_t crc64(const void* src, unsigned long len, const unsigned char* seed)
{
   const u8* b = (const u8*)src;
   u64 crc = INITIAL_CRC64;

   for (unint i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      crc = CRC64_Table[(u8)(crc >> 56) ^ *b++] ^ (crc << 8);
   }
   b = (const u8*)seed;

   for (unint i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      crc = CRC64_Table[(u8)(crc >> 56) ^ *b++] ^ (crc << 8);
   }
   return ~crc;
}



const size_t bloomMaxEntry = 131072 * 4;

typedef uint64_t(*hashAlgo)(const void* src, unsigned long src_sz, const unsigned char* seed);

const unsigned char hashSeed[8][16]  = { { 0xba, 0xda, 0xfe, 0xc5, 0xcd, 0xea, 0xba, 0x4e, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x9a, 0xbc, 0xde, 0xfa },
                                         { 0xbb, 0xdb, 0xfb, 0xcb, 0xcd, 0x1a, 0x2a, 0xee, 0x42, 0xb4, 0x5e, 0x18, 0x5a, 0x0c, 0x34, 0xb2 },
                                         { 0xbc, 0xdc, 0xfc, 0xcc, 0xcd, 0xe1, 0xb1, 0x41, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x9a, 0xbc, 0xde, 0xfa },
                                         { 0xbd, 0xdd, 0xfd, 0xcd, 0xdd, 0xe3, 0xc1, 0x81, 0xd2, 0x33, 0x56, 0x78, 0x9a, 0xbc, 0xde, 0xfa },
                                         { 0x1a, 0x4a, 0xae, 0x15, 0x5d, 0x9a, 0x5a, 0x1e, 0xc2, 0x31, 0xc6, 0x48, 0xda, 0x1c, 0xae, 0xf4 },
                                         { 0x2b, 0x3b, 0xbb, 0x2b, 0x6d, 0x8a, 0x4a, 0x0e, 0xd2, 0xb2, 0xde, 0x38, 0xea, 0x2c, 0xb4, 0xb5 },
                                         { 0x3c, 0x2c, 0xcc, 0x3c, 0x7d, 0x71, 0x31, 0x21, 0xe2, 0x3a, 0xe6, 0x28, 0xfa, 0x3d, 0xce, 0xf6 },
                                         { 0x4d, 0x1d, 0xdd, 0x4d, 0x8d, 0x63, 0x21, 0x31, 0xf2, 0x3e, 0xf6, 0x18, 0x8a, 0x4c, 0xde, 0xf7 }
};


void testBloomHash(uint32_t numHash, uint32_t sizeBloom, uint32_t numEntries, hashAlgo hashFnct)
{
   uint32_t bloomLoop = 2000000;
   uint64_t maxRandom = 0xffffffffffffffff;
   std::default_random_engine generator;
   std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> distribution(0, maxRandom);
   std::set<uint64_t> randomSet;
   std::bitset<bloomMaxEntry> bloomFilter;

   assert(bloomMaxEntry >= numEntries);

   double k = numHash;
   double n = numEntries;
   double m = sizeBloom;
   double p = pow(1.0 - pow((1.0 - (double)1.0 / (double)m), (double)k * n), (double)k);

   uint64_t* bloomHash = new uint64_t[numHash];
   uint64_t falsePositive = 0;

   bloomFilter.reset();
   randomSet.clear();

   // Seed the Bloom filter with a number of entries.

   for (uint64_t i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {

      uint64_t value;
      while (true) {
         value = distribution(generator);
         if (randomSet.find(value) != randomSet.end()) {
            continue;
         }
         randomSet.insert(value);
         break;
      }

      for (uint32_t j = 0; j < numHash; j++) {
         bloomHash[j] = hashFnct(&value, sizeof(uint64_t), hashSeed[j]) % sizeBloom;
         bloomFilter[bloomHash[j]] = 1;
      }
   }
   // Test appartenance of bloomLoop entries against new values and compute the false positive.

   for (uint64_t k = 0; k < bloomLoop; k++) {
      uint64_t value;

      // We want random number that wasn't previously generated. Thus all the next values generated should return negative when
      // testing against the bloom filter. This will enable the computing of false positive probability.

      while (true) {
         value = distribution(generator);
         if (randomSet.find(value) != randomSet.end()) {
            continue;
         }
         randomSet.insert(value);
         break;
      }
      // Hash function for random value
      for (uint32_t j = 0; j < numHash; j++) {
         bloomHash[j] = hashFnct(&value, sizeof(uint64_t), hashSeed[j]) % sizeBloom;
      }
      bool testBloomSet = 1;
      for (uint32_t j = 0; j < numHash; j++) {
         testBloomSet &= bloomFilter[bloomHash[j]];
      }
      if (!testBloomSet) {
         continue;
      }
      else {
         falsePositive++;
      }
   }
   assert(randomSet.size() == (bloomLoop + numEntries));

   std::cout << "Theoritical false positive probability = " << p << ", 1 in " << (uint64_t)(1.0 / p) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Simulation false positives = " << falsePositive << " out of " << bloomLoop << " values: false positive probability = " << (double)falsePositive / (double)(bloomLoop) << ", 1 in " << (uint64_t)((double)(bloomLoop) / (double)falsePositive) << std::endl << std::endl;

   delete[] bloomHash;
}



int main()
{
   uint32_t numEntries = 8192;

   numEntries = 8192;
   std::cout << "--- Testing siphash with entries = " << numEntries << " ---" << std::endl << std::endl;
   testBloomHash(8, 262144, numEntries, siphash);

   std::cout << "--- Testing crc64 with entries = " << numEntries << " ---" << std::endl << std::endl;
   testBloomHash(8, 262144, numEntries, crc64);
}
```

The simulation execution return:

--- Testing siphash with entries = 8192 ---

Theoritical false positive probability = 5.73158e-06, 1 in 174471
Simulation false positives = 13 out of 2000000 values: false positive probability = 6.5e-06, 1 in 153846

--- Testing crc64 with entries = 8192 ---

Theoritical false positive probability = 5.73158e-06, 1 in 174471
Simulation false positives = 61775 out of 2000000 values: false positive probability = 0.0308875, 1 in 32

Comment: Worth noting that mixing the seed into the CRC in this manner is the equivalent of XORing a constant into the output of the CRC. You can get the second hash by taking the first hash and XORing 0xbc2ca2e7950da15c into it, you can get the third hash by taking the first hash and XORing 0xd2970b941b7a3ee7 into it. Etc. This is the same constant no matter what the starting hash is. Not sure if this is the cause of your problem but it seems suspicious.

Comment: @NickODell This is a noteworthy observation. Indeed this would mean that a relationship would exist between each CRC64 hashing function which would violate the rule that no relationship should exist between each hashing function. You might be right. Let see if someone can provide a theoretical analysis of this relationship to prove the point.

Comment: @NickODel You were right. Bloom filter needs hashing independence. If you google with keywords: "bloom" "filter" "hash" "independent" you'll find papers that explain you need hashing independence.  Obviously how I use the seed for CRC32 which adds only a constant break the rule of independence.

Answer (score 1):

Using the CRC mod 262144, only the lower 18 bits are significant.

There are effectively 262144 possible distinct hash values, and you added 8192 entries.

The chance that a new random entry has effectively the same hash as one you already added is about 8192/262144 = 1/32, as your experiment shows.

You'd do much better with `sizeBloom = 262139`.

Comment: The explanation is true only if you use one hashing (k=1). You can check this yourself with a Bloom filter calculator ( https://hur.st/bloomfilter/?n=8192&p=&m=262144&k=1 ). But the problem is the code uses 8 Hashing and is reducing to the behaviour of a single hashing.  As pinpointed by @NickODell, the seed used only adds a constant. Thus a hashing relationship exists between all the 8 hashes. This breaks the rule of a Bloom filter design which should use hash functions that are independent from each other.

Comment: @GuyB The "8 hash functions" are created by prefixing the data processed by the CRC.  As mentioned in comments on the question, that has the effect of just XORing a single CRC hash with 8 different constant values.  When the modulus is taken only the lower 18 bits of the original hash, and those constants, is significant.  If A and B have the same lower 18 CRC bits, then ALL 8 of their resulting hashes will be equal.